# obtaining statistic from SQL Database HTML

Tags: html, sql

Given a database “firstdb” that contain a table “TAB1”. This table is nothing more than students information that can be showed as follow

```
ID   Last Name    First Name    Date of Birth      School             Specialty    Sex
01    yves          marco        03/03/2000      la roccade school      letter     man
02    marchal       zeko         05-12-1999      johara school          letter     man
03    ghisil        maria        15-03-2000      johara school          science    women
04    belbali       john         30-10-1999      lever school           science    man
05    santa         sofi         04-05-2000      la roccade school      science    women
06    yves          don          16/04/2000      la roccade school      lette      man
```

The perpos if to extract a statistic using this data and based on some colon: “ School, Specialty , sex” where the result should be  as follow:

```
School          Specialty       Sex       number
la roccade school   letter      man         02
la roccade school    letter     women       00
la roccade school   science     man         00
la roccade school   science     women       01
johara school       letter      man         01
johara school       letter      women       00
johara school       science     man         00
johara school       science     women       01
lever school        letter      man         00
lever school        letter      women       00
lever school        science     man         01
lever school        science     women       00
```

PS: the amount of data is not fixed. Where it’s canchange.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for a query to get the desired results? This should work:

```
SELECT
    School,
    Specialty,
    Sex,
    COUNT(ID) AS Number
FROM TAB1
GROUP BY
    School,
    Specialty,
    Sex;
```

Comment: it s working just fine thanks. the problem now is in displaying that data. meaning: displaying only the columns showed in the second table: _"School, Specialty, Sex"_ . as well as creating a new columns named _"numbers"_ to show the statistics.  thank you very much.